# Why does my Package not work when I use ParallelEvaluate?

Tags: parallelization, packages, contexts

I am developing a package in Mathematica for finding the conductivity of magnetic materials. The most important and time consuming processes are EigenSystem[] calls. I want to make the code modular so I am developing a separate package that construct the matrix which ultimately gets sent to EigenSystem[]. I have run into behavior that I do not understand when I try to parallelize my code. The parallelization is trivial, e.g., loop over multiple parameter values in parallel and run the expensive calculation in serial for each value.

Below is a sample code that shows the unexpected behavior. In the first example I define a function test0[size_] that builds the identity matrix with dimensions size^2. Next I find the Eigenvalues[] and return the first entry. Finally I evaluate the expression in parallel and the result is as expected.

```
In[0]: test0[size_]:=IdentityMatrix[size];
In[1]: Eigenvalues[test0[2]][[1]]
In[2]: ParallelEvaluate[Eigenvalues[test0[2]][[1]]]

Out[1]: 1

Out[2]: {1, 1}
```

In the second example I perform essentially the same operations, with one crucial difference: now when I define the function I do so in a different context. This is a crucial component of making nice Mathematica package. Now when I evaluate the code in serial I get the same behavior as the function test0[], but when I evaluate in parallel the behavior is quite strange. The output is simply the matrix itself.

```
In[3]: BeginPackage["testing`"];
         test1[size_]:=IdentityMatrix[size];
       EndPackage[];
In[4]: Eigenvalues[test1[2]][[1]]
In[5]: ParallelEvaluate[Eigenvalues[test1[2]][[1]]]

Out[4]: 1

Out[5]: {{{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}
```

What is even more strange to me is if I remove the [[1]] indexing of the Eigenvalues the behavior is as expected.

```
In[6]: ParallelEvaluate[Eigenvalues[test1[2]]]

Out[6]: {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}
```

Comment: If going down the package route `ParallelNeeds` is worth looking at (and/or possibly with some initialization finessing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No idea if this is a bug, but you can work around it by using

```
ParallelEvaluate[Eigenvalues[test1[2]][[1]], 
 DistributedContexts -> {"testing`"}]
(* {1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

Or, with the same effect, you can evaluate

```
$DistributedContexts = {"Global`", "testing`"}
ParallelEvaluate[Eigenvalues[test1[2]][[1]]]
(* {"Global`", "testing`"} *)
(* {1, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

Comment: Thanks! Everything works when I use DistributedContexts. I guess the surprising thing is that ParallelEvaluate[Eigenvalues[...]] works without DistributedContexts, but ParallelEvaluate[Eigenvalues[...][[1]]] fails without giving an error message and with an unexpected return value.